# How to do a batch run to apply "XAML styler" to all xaml files in a Visual Studio 2019 project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, plugins, formatting

Our team just decided to use XAML styler for all of our .xaml files. Since we already have a large codebase we want to apply the styling for all existing files to have a clean start.

Is there a plugin for Visual Studio 2019 which can apply XAML styler plugin to all xaml files in the project? I tried Google but wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, *XAML Styler* will format each **opened** XAML file when saving. Therefore, the manual way would be to open all XAML files and *Save* or *Save All*.

Alternatively, you can just create a command line script for all XAML files and run *XAML Styler* on it, see [this page in the GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/wiki/Batch-File) there is already an example.

If you are looking for an extension that will do the same in Visual Studio directly, use [*Format All Files*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.FormatAllFiles). It explicitly supports formatting all XAML files in a project or solution with *XAML Styler*.

> You can change the options in "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Format All Files". [...]
>
> If you want to format XAML files, install XAML Styler and set the option "Other Execution Command" to "EditorContextMenus.XAMLEditor.FormatXAML".